# How to handle async code inside Meteor.js Accounts.registerLoginHandler

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am registering a custom login Handler for OTP based authentication.

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(async function(loginRequest){
    if (!loginRequest.sms) return;
    let user = await handelLogin(loginRequest);
    console.log(user);
    return user;
});
```

In the above code `handelLogin(loginRequest)` is an asynchronous function and returns `{userId:'.....'}` after doing a network request and verifying OTP code.
When called this login handler from client i am getting this error

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: A login method must      specify a userId or an error
```

with some googling I found i need to wait for `user` variable to have value and then return it, so I used `async` and `await` in above code.
But still getting same error.

After this 'login' Error this `console.log(user);` from above code is logged on server console after some time.

1. Why is it not returning `user` ?
2. Any suggestions or another way to achieve this.

Comment: he tells you A login method must      specify a userId or an error

Comment: Wait; since when can we use async/await with Meteor? Oo

Comment: hey, but my handelLogin(loginRequest) is async so callback of Accounts.registerLoginHandler need to wait for user variable to have some value or error and then return that. But i think its returning undefined which is causing login error. So is there a better way to wait for async code to complete?

Comment: @JulienLeray from meteor 1.3 i think we can use async/await. I found here https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-declare-async-function-myfunction-inside-meteor-methods-so-that-front-end-can-call-it/25991/2

Comment: wow that's really cool I need to try that. For your issue; I can't find the registerLoginHandler method on the meteor doc api... where did you find it?

Comment: @JulienLeray I found here https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts/ but instead of this `return {id: userId}` you need to return this `return {userId: userId}` . You can find this in comments of that  post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts.registerLoginHandler() is not ready for async/await. It expects a function, not a Promise. (An async function returns a Promise).

So yes, you can use Promises and async/await in your own server side code, but not in this particular case.

The easiest way to get this to work, assuming that you are at liberty to change the signature of `handleLogin()`, is to convert it from returning a Promise into the older NodeJS convention of having a `callback( error, result )` function as its last argument, and then wrapping the call to that with [`Meteor.wrapAsync()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync).

Your code (using the modified handleLogin()) becomes something like:

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest){
    ...
    let handleLoginSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(handleLogin, this); // Change 'this' to whatever context handleLogin expects.
    let user = handelLoginSync(loginRequest);
    ...
});
```